# View.setX is transforming my circle background to a square

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a custom switch (from scratch). I'm showing a circle over a line, and when the view is clicked, I'm using setX to move the circle. But when I do, this, the circle becomes a square, and on successive clicks it stays a square

I have this for my custom view

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_slider_widget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View    
            android:id="@+id/search_slider_line"    
            android:layout_width="@dimen/search_slider_line"    
            android:layout_height="@dimen/search_slider_circle"    
            android:background="@drawable/slider_line"></View>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/search_slider_circle"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/search_slider_circle"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/search_slider_circle"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/slider_circle">
        </View>
    </FrameLayout>
</merge>
```

This is the circle drawable that's used as background

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#999999" />
    <size
        android:width="@dimen/search_slider_circle"
        android:height="@dimen/search_slider_circle" />
</shape>
```

And the code to move the circle

```
float x = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.search_slider_line) - getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.search_slider_circle);
circleView.setX(x);
```

I was using ObjectAnimator to perform the circle transition, but that wasn't the problem, since setX or setTranslationX still have the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have mistakes in the other parts of your code, I tried to achieve animation which you want and had no issues. You may try to move your view using margins also, but I guess that problem is somewhere else.

Comment: You were right, that wasn't the problem, it was that I was updating the backgroundColor of the View incorrectly, I was using setBackgroundColor thinking that it would update the shape fill and I think it was replacing it. Getting the background and then setting the color did the trick. Thanks for settting me in the correct path!